# A good project-mangament system for communicate, bugtrack etc

Tags: project-management

I am looking for a good app / website that would have
 * some issue tracking system
 * maybe documentation managment system
 * possibility of creating chat rooms, or at least one group chat.
 * Todo lists

Do you know something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I guess that we are talking about software development. Generally, there are plenty of tools available - differing in features an payment model (commercial/open source). [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) by example is a nice open source software, which covers most of your desired features (may be some plugins are needed).

I think the first question you should ask yourself is if you want to host it or use a turnkey ready system by a provider.

For the first option - plan some time to setup and maintain your project management environment. I don't think there is one product available fitting your needs. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aProject_management_software) pages are a good starter for an overview.

If you want to start quickly the second option is your option and it sounds for me like you should have a look at Atlassian [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview/team-collaboration-software) for team collaboration. If you can install plugins there is a [chat plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/confluence.chat)) available or alternatively you can use a second Atlassian product named [HipChat](https://www.atlassian.com/software/hipchat/overview). You also want to have a look at [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) for issue and project tracking.

Well, the good thing is if you are open source you can use most of these tools somehow for "free" (details on the website of each product). For commercial projects it costs some money, but in my opinion the pricing is ok.

Hope that helped a bit.

*Jost

Comment: Thank you for your answer a lot! Thats something iv'e expected. But what do you think about redmine ? Did you used it ? Can you compare it to your recommendations ?

Comment: I've no deep experiences with [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). What I've heard from other developers it is a nice tool with a big user community. This is an important aspect, because you don't want to use a software which is not maintained actively or at least from time to time you might need some help from the community ;-).

Comment: Finally, I see nothing which speaks against Redmine. You have to decide if the features fit your needs and please don't forget the maintenance aspects. Normally such tools are essential for the business and need to be kept running.